# Why on daf 56b in Bavah Kamah, tosafos mymid, is the thief chayiv for whatever mazik that animal does if it is not their animal

Tags: gezel-stealing, tosfot, bava-kamma

Good sources, good clear answers,and very thought through. I already tried with the English but I didn't get it.

Comment: Why wouldn't he be?

Comment: You mentioned you used the English, but which one? Try the one on the Daf Yomi Advancement Forum (https://www.dafyomi.co.il/bkama/tosfos/bk-ts-056.htm, number 11) and see if that helps.